# change text every time button clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, text

I've searched a lot but can't find an answer...

I have a list of quotes and every time I click the button I want it to go to a new quote.
Can someone please explain what's wrong here and how I should fix it?

```
<script language="Javascript">    

    function buttonClickHandler() {

        var textField = document.getElementById("textField"); 

        var quotes = new Array();
        var nextQuote = 0;
        quotes[0] = "Don't be so humble - you are not that great.";
        quotes[1] = "Moral indignation is jealousy with a halo.";
        quotes[2] = "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.";
        quotes[3] = "The fundamental cause of trouble in the world is that the stupid are cocksure while the intelligent are full of doubt.";
        quotes[4] = "Victory goes to the player who makes the next-to-last mistake.";
        quotes[5] = "His ignorance is encyclopedic";
        quotes[6] = "If a man does his best, what else is there?";
        quotes[7] = "Political correctness is tyranny with manners.";
        quotes[8] = "You can avoid reality, but you cannot avoid the consequences of avoiding reality.";
        quotes[9] = "When one person suffers from a delusion it is called insanity; when many people suffer from a delusion it is called religion.";

        nextQuote++;
        textField.value = quotes[nextQuote];       
    }
</script>
```

I found this code on the internet and when I use this code, it changes the text on every click.

```
        var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);

        // Add one
       currentValue++;

        // Put it back with the new +1'd value
        textField.value = currentValue;
        var quotes = new Array();
```

The code I used for my array is nearly the same but it doesn't change the text per click. Is there something special I need to do for arrays? Help!!

Comment: You could use a combo of `pop` and `push` indefinitely to rotate the quotes instead of maintaining a counter.

Comment: How are you calling `buttonClickHandler`? If you call it every time, it'll always show your first quote since you're initializing `nextQuote` every time.

Comment: You are reseting `nextQuote` to zero each time you run the click handler. That makes quotes 1 to 9 excess luggage.

Comment: check this: http://jsbin.com/OFIliHUs/1/edit

Comment: I meant `shift` and `push`, basically shift a value, store it in a var, then push it to the end.

Comment: Don't use the constructor pattern `new Array()` to make an array, just use an [array literal](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2151-when-to-use-the-array-literal-notation-in-javascript/) instead: `var quotes = [];`. Any tutorial that uses `new Array()` is likely very old and outdated and will probably teach you more bad habits than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont change it because you declare the array and the index inside your handler, so every time you click you get the quote at index 1. Define the index outside the handler (as well as the array) and increment inside the handler:

```
var quotes = new Array();
    var nextQuote = 0;
    quotes[0] = "Don't be so humble - you are not that great.";
    quotes[1] = "Moral indignation is jealousy with a halo.";
    quotes[2] = "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.";
    quotes[3] = "The fundamental cause of trouble in the world is that the stupid are cocksure while the intelligent are full of doubt.";
    quotes[4] = "Victory goes to the player who makes the next-to-last mistake.";
    quotes[5] = "His ignorance is encyclopedic";
    quotes[6] = "If a man does his best, what else is there?";
    quotes[7] = "Political correctness is tyranny with manners.";
    quotes[8] = "You can avoid reality, but you cannot avoid the consequences of avoiding reality.";
    quotes[9] = "When one person suffers from a delusion it is called insanity; when many people suffer from a delusion it is called religion.";

function buttonClickHandler() {
    var textField = document.getElementById("textField");
    textField.value = [++nextQuote];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because every time the function is called **nextQuote** is re-set to 0

Answer (score 0):

You're assinging nextQuote to 0 every single time you call the handler.

`var nextQuote = 0;`

Try doing this instead:

```
var quotes = new Array();
    quotes[0] = "Don't be so humble - you are not that great.";
    quotes[1] = "Moral indignation is jealousy with a halo.";
    quotes[2] = "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.";
    quotes[3] = "The fundamental cause of trouble in the world is that the stupid are cocksure while the intelligent are full of doubt.";
    quotes[4] = "Victory goes to the player who makes the next-to-last mistake.";
    quotes[5] = "His ignorance is encyclopedic";
    quotes[6] = "If a man does his best, what else is there?";
    quotes[7] = "Political correctness is tyranny with manners.";
    quotes[8] = "You can avoid reality, but you cannot avoid the consequences of avoiding reality.";
    quotes[9] = "When one person suffers from a delusion it is called insanity; when many people suffer from a delusion it is called religion.";

var nextQuote = 0;
var textField = document.getElementById("textField"); 


function buttonClickHandler() {
    if(nextQuote < 9) {
        nextQuote++;
    } else {
        nextQuote = 0;
    }
    textField.value = quotes[nextQuote];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

var nextQuote = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);

instead of your:

var nextQuote =0;

later change the 9 to your array size, and add it after you've declared all the values into your array.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the code that works gets the value to increment from outside of buttonClickHandler

var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);

where as you reinitialise it every time buttonClickHandler is called

var nextQuote = 0;

I think it will work if you replace this declaration with

```
if (window.nextQuote == null) {
   window.nextQuote = 0 
} else {
   window.nextQuote++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously posted answers have already stated, the problem is caused because `nextQuote` is defined inside of `buttonClickHandler` and thus destroyed every time the function finishes executing and is recreated and initialized to `0` every time the function begins.

You seem to be learning JavaScript using some very old tutorials, the following code will show how this could be refactored to a more modern style.

`<script language="Javascript">`The [`language` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) of the `<script>` tag was deprecated a very long time ago. Don't use it. It was replaced by the `type` attribute, however [don't use the `type` attribute either](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=936s). Just a plain `<script>` tag works in all browsers, they all default to JavaScript since it was the only language to ever gain any traction as a client-side scripting language.

```
<script>
(function (document) { // Use a self-invoking function to keep our variables
                       // out of the global scope

  "use strict"; // Force the browser into strict mode

  var nextQuote = 0, // instead of using separate var statements you can use
                     // a comma to include all of your variable declarations
                     // in one statement.

    /* Since we will be using the textField DOM element a lot, lets cache a
       copy in a variable outside of the handler instead of enduring the
       overhead of getElementById every time the handler runs,
       querying the DOM is slow.
    */
    textField = document.getElementById("textField"),

    /* Instead of using new Array(), use an array literal. Literals are
       shorter and behave in a more predictable way than the Array
       constructor. Another benefit to using a literal is that you can
       create the array and initialize it's values in one step avoiding
       the tedious quotes[0] = "..."; quotes[1] = "..."; pattern of the
       original code. Also, if you want to reorder the items in the list
       you don't have to renumber them too.
    */
    quotes = [
      "Don't be so humble - you are not that great.",
      "Moral indignation is jealousy with a halo.",
      "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.",
      "The fundamental cause of trouble in the world is that the stupid are cocksure while the intelligent are full of doubt.",
      "Victory goes to the player who makes the next-to-last mistake.",
      "His ignorance is encyclopedic",
      "If a man does his best, what else is there?",
      "Political correctness is tyranny with manners.",
      "You can avoid reality, but you cannot avoid the consequences of avoiding reality.",
      // The last item in the list should not have a comma after it, some
      // browsers will ignore it but others will throw an error.
      "When one person suffers from a delusion it is called insanity; when many people suffer from a delusion it is called religion."
    ];

  function buttonClickHandler() {
      nextQuote++;
      // roll back to 0 if we reach the end
      if (nextQuote >= quotes.length) {
        nextQuote = 0;
      }

      textField.value = quotes[nextQuote];       
  }

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
}(document)); /* This is the end of the self-invoking function. The document
                 object is being passed in as an argument. It will be imported
                 into the self-invoking function as a local variable also named
                 document. There are a couple of reasons to do this. Having it
                 aliased as a local variable will make any references to it
                 quicker since the browser will not have to look any further
                 up the scope-chain. Also, if this code is minified, the local
                 variable will be renamed to a shorter (often 1 character long)
                 name, saving download time, where references to the built-in
                 global document object would not.
               */

</script>
```

The [self-invoking function](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/advanced-javascript/) that wraps the code is a very common pattern in modern JavaScript, it would be good to become familiar with it.

Using [strict mode](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/) will help you avoid a number of easy to create bugs.

If you are deploying JavaScript code into the wild you should be [minifying](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#MinifyJS) it. Having a build process can make this easy by automating it for you. I would recommend [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), it has lots of pre-built tasks to make minifying and other common build tasks easy. It can be a bit tricky to set up at first but there are a lot of great articles out there that can make it much easier to understand.